# Microsoft Edge extension context menu not appearing

Tags: javascript, browser, contextmenu, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

I'm trying to create my first Edge extension after being forced to use the browser for a while and finding that I actually quite like it.

My extension just shows a new context menu entry on the page. The extension loads in Edge and appears in the extensions pane along with the meta data (description, version etc) but the context menu itself doesn't show when I right click the page.

Any one familiar with Edge extensions know why? Here's the code.

index.js

---

```
browser.contextMenus.create({
id: "MyMenu",
title: "My Context Item",
contexts: ['page']
});

browser.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
if (info.menuItemId == "MyMenu") {

Code goes here;

    }
});
```

manifest.json

---

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "MyMenu",
  "version": "1.0.0",

  "description": "My Menu.",
  "author": "Oliver Marshall",

  "permissions": ["contextMenus"],

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["index.js"],
    "persistent": true
  }
}
```

It's fairly boilerplate stuff, in fact it is boilerplate stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that while the extension loads, context menu handlers appear to require a restart of the browser for the menu item to be created.

After reloading Edge, and re-enabling the extension, the context menu is showing.